# Convert SQL Server stored procedure to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to convert the following stored procedure of SQL Server to MySQL. I am new to MySQL.

```
    CREATE PROC InsertGenerator
(@tableName varchar(100)) as
--Declare a cursor to retrieve column specific information 
--for the specified table
DECLARE cursCol CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR 
SELECT column_name,data_type FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name = @tableName
OPEN cursCol
DECLARE @string nvarchar(3000) 

--for storing the first half 
--of INSERT statement

DECLARE @stringData nvarchar(3000) 

--for storing the data 
--(VALUES) related statement

DECLARE @dataType nvarchar(1000) --data types returned 

--for respective columns

SET @string='INSERT '+@tableName+'('
SET @stringData=''

DECLARE @colName nvarchar(50)

FETCH NEXT FROM cursCol INTO @colName,@dataType

IF @@fetch_status<>0
    begin
    print 'Table '+@tableName+' not found, processing skipped.'
    close curscol
    deallocate curscol
    return
END
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
IF @dataType in ('varchar','char','nchar','nvarchar')
BEGIN
    SET @stringData=@stringData+'''''''''+
            isnull('+@colName+','''')+'''''',''+'
END
ELSE

if @dataType in ('text','ntext')

 --if the datatype 
 --is text or something else 

BEGIN
    SET @stringData=@stringData+'''''''''+
          isnull(cast('+@colName+' as varchar(2000)),'''')+'''''',''+'
END

ELSE
IF @dataType = 'money' --because money doesn't get converted 

--from varchar implicitly

BEGIN

    SET @stringData=@stringData+'''convert(money,''''''+
        isnull(cast('+@colName+' as varchar(200)),''0.0000'')+''''''),''+'

END
ELSE 
IF @dataType='datetime'
BEGIN
    SET @stringData=@stringData+'''convert(datetime,''''''+
        isnull(cast('+@colName+' as varchar(200)),''0'')+''''''),''+'
END
ELSE 
IF @dataType='image' 
BEGIN

    SET @stringData=@stringData+'''''''''+
       isnull(cast(convert(varbinary,'+@colName+') 
       as varchar(6)),''0'')+'''''',''+'
END
ELSE 

--presuming the data type is int,bit,numeric,decimal 

BEGIN

    SET @stringData=@stringData+'''''''''+
          isnull(cast('+@colName+' as varchar(200)),''0'')+'''''',''+'
END
SET @string=@string+@colName+','
FETCH NEXT FROM cursCol INTO @colName,@dataType
END
```

Comment: You need to format your question properly so that all your SQL is displayed as a code block.

Comment: @Graham Clark, the code formatted now. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: It still isn't properly formatted. Select the whole block of code and click the code icon. Also what is your question? Is it can you rewrite this whole chunk of code for for me? If so I suspect the answer will be a resounding no!

Comment: This question should be closed as "too broad".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines-syntax.html
This link contains the documentation on creating stored procedures and functions in MySql. You have quite a lot of code there so it may come down to 6 of 1 and half dozen of the other.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert it to MySQL by using the following steps.

1. In SQL Server the parameters of the stored procedure are declared as

   For Example:

   CREATE PROCEDURE Strproc_example(
       @strBillingPeriodID VarChar(200),
       @result int OUT)

   In MySQL it is

   CREATE PROCEDURE Strproc_example(
       v_strBillingPeriodID VarChar(200),
           OUT v_result int )
2. In SQL server there is the `As` keyword. Remove that in MySQL
3. Then put a semicolon after in statement of SQL Server to convert it
   into MySQL statements.